# What value actually need to provide {item-path} in view.delta OneDrive for Business API

Tags: onedrive

I am using `/drive/root:/{item-path}:/view.delta` for getting the changes of a file in OneDrive for Business in root folder. I have tried with the path like `/drive/root:/Files/filename:/view.delta` but the response is resource not found. Can someone please explain what exactly this value ?

The link I am following is below.

[more details](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The error would suggest that `/Files/filename` does not exist, however even if it did you'd run into another limitation of how `view.delta` currently works with OneDrive for Business. To make a long story short, it's limited to only working on the root of the drive, i.e. `/drive/root/view.delta`. Using this path you'll get back changes for ALL items within the drive, not just the one that you're interested in.

Given that you're trying to detect changes in a single file you may want to consider a standard metadata request with an `If-None-Match` header that contains the ETag of the last state your application saw.

---

For example, you'd first make a request without any additional headers to get the initial state:

Request:

```
GET /_api/v2.0/drive/root:/File/filename
```

Response:

```
200 OK
{
  ...
  "name": "filename",
  "etag": "\"aasdfasdf\"",
  "modifiedDateTime": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  ...
}
```

---

At some point in the future you'd then make a call using the etag value in the `If-None-Match` header:

Request:

```
GET /_api/v2.0/drive/root:/File/filename
If-None-Match: "aasdfasdf"
```

Response:

```
304 Not Modified
```

---

If the file has actually changed you'd get back the new response.

Request:

```
GET /_api/v2.0/drive/root:/File/filename
If-None-Match: "aasdfasdf"
```

Response:

```
200 OK
{
  ...
  "name": "filename",
  "etag": "\"poihklhjl\"",
  "modifiedDateTime": "2016-04-19T00:00:00Z",
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am looking for the revision history of a file. I could not find this API in the list. Is there any API available for this or I need to do standard metadata request with an If-None-Match.

Comment: Version history is not yet exposed via the API, and while we cannot comment on timelines it's definitely on our radar. The delta API (and similarly the method I outlined in this answer) are only for notifying a client when a file or folder changes, NOT what actually changed.

Comment: Thanks for the help Brad.